# Data is not being scraped correctly

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to scrape the following webpage using Scrapy, https://www2.trollandtoad.com/buylist/?_ga=2.123753418.115346513.1562026676-1813285172.1559913561#!/M/10591, and I got part of the data scraped correctly but I cannot get the card name scraped correctly because the selector for it is the same as the set name so I just get the set name for the card name as well.

```
 def parse(self, response):
        #  Initialize item to function GameItem located in items.py, will be called multiple times
        item = GameItem()
        # Extract card category from URL using html code from website that identifies the category.  Will be outputted before rest of data
        for data in response.css("tr.ng-scope"):
            item["Set"] =data.css("a.ng-binding.ng-scope::text").get()
            if item["Set"] == None:
                item["Set"] = data.css("span.ng-binding.ng-scope::text").get()
            item["Card_Name"] = data.css("a.ng-binding.ng-scope::text").get()
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = data.css("td\.5557170.buylist_condition::text").get()
            item["Quantity"] = data.css("span.ng-binding::text").get()
            item["Price"] = data.css("span.ng-binding::text").get()
```

**UPDATE #1**

I used xpath instead and was able to get a card name instead of the set name, but it is returning the same card name for each line instead of a different one.

```
item["Card_Name"] = data.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()").get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is what finally got it working correctly, I had to trim down my xpath and make it relative instead of absolute.

```
item["Card_Name"]  = data.xpath(".//td[2]/a/text()").get()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
card_names = response.xpath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,'buylist_productname item')]/a/text()").getall()
```

Will return list of different card names according to their order in the page.